# Why can't I get DateAdd() to work in VBA MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

As typical MS Access is making simple things hard...

The two lines:

```
  now = now()
  twoYearsAgo = DateAdd("m", -24, now)
```

produces the error on the second line:

```
 Object Required
```

Before it also had an error about an array...

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reserved words, properties in Access VBA.  This might help:

[Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)

Comment: Thanks,we have a winner! On the other hand it's possible the corporate network doesn't like the link or its broken

Comment: I didn't have an issue accessing the link, but in a nutshell - `Now` is VBA function name so not a good choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively doing:

```
now = now
```

So do like this:

```
Dim ThisMoment As Date
Dim TwoYearsAgo As Date

ThisMoment = Now
TwoYearsAgo = DateAdd("m", -24, ThisMoment )
```